# MS-ACCESS: Multiple Filters

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to have a way to let the user click multiple checkboxes and lists, to filter a subform. When I try to use an `AND` statement, I get an error: `Run-time rror '13': Type mismatch`. I put an arrow to the line in question. Is an `And` statement not valid syntax for filtering this way?

```
Private Sub SearchB_Click()

If Me![CoreCB] = True Then

    Me.Query1SF.Form.Filter = " IsDate([Core RS]) = True"
    Me.Query1SF.Form.FilterOn = True

ElseIf Me![SiteCB] = True Then

    Me.Query1SF.Form.Filter = " IsDate([Site RS]) = True"
    Me.Query1SF.Form.FilterOn = True

    If Not IsNull(SiteCombo.Value) Then

      -->  Me.Query1SF.Form.Filter = "[Location] = '" & Me.[SiteCombo].Value & "'" And " IsDate([Site RS]) = True" '!! THIS DOESN'T WORK
        Me.Query1SF.Form.FilterOn = True

    End If

ElseIf Me![SecurityCB] = True Then

    Me.Query1SF.Form.Filter = " IsDate([Security]) = True"
    Me.Query1SF.Form.FilterOn = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try this  `Me.Query1SF.Form.Filter = "[Location]='" & Me.[SiteCombo].Value & "' And IsDate([Site RS])=True" `

Comment: Yup, that did it! If you like, please make this into an answer for me to accept. Also, if your so inclined, can you explain a bit regarding the syntax of the "  "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String expression for form filter seems incorrect. Use below line

```
Me.Query1SF.Form.Filter = "[Location]='" & Me.[SiteCombo].Value & "' And IsDate([Site RS])=True"
```